# Laravel5 illuminate composer messagebag package

Tags: php, laravel-5, package, message

I'd like to install the `illuminate/support/messagebag` but can't seem to find a composer address to do this.

Is this still available for Laravel5 and if so, what composer details do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a general purpouse message package, you can try [this one here](https://github.com/edvinaskrucas/notification), if you just need a Flash message bag, you can try [this one](https://github.com/laracasts/flash)

EDIT: As I said in the comments, I thought you needed another one. MessageBag is there, wasn't removed. I've done a fresh installation and I got it working. Check my composer.json, there's nothing rare in there, just laravel:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
```

Maybe there's a problem with your installation, but it should be there.

Comment: I was hoping I could just grab the original messagebag, to avoid even more changes. Does it no longer exist? It seems to be [laravel 5 supported](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html)

Comment: i thought you needed another. It's there by default, you dont have to install anything, just add "use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag" at the top of your class and you are good to go.

Comment: Not there on my installation.